# VirtualBox Host-only: guests can't talk between themselves?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, osx-leopard

I'm using a host-only network with VirtualBox on macOS Sierra, my guests are Ubuntu. My **Host** (*192.168.56.1*) can ping both **Guest A** (*192.168.56.100*) and **Guest B** (*192.168.56.101*). Each guest can ping **Host**, but *guests can't ping each other*.

**Guest A** routing table:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.56.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s3
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s3
```

**Guest B** routing table:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.56.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s3
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
```

Because **Host** can talk to guests and each guest can talk to **Host**, I get a feeling that the host is not forwarding traffic between the guests.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to different SE sites. Pick one & stick with it - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285394/virtualbox-host-only-guests-cant-talk-between-themselves

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem, answering in case it helps others.

If using the default `vboxnet0` host-only settings, `192.168.56.100` is taken by the DHCP server.

My problem is that I gave one of my guests (**Guest A** above) the static IP of the DHCP server.

Just avoid that IP or change the host-only network's settings.